# Performance impact on enabling the Service broker at database level?

Tags: sql-server-2012, signalr

I was working on a POC for pushing the database notifications to the UI using SignalR using the following articles:

- [Database Change Notifications in ASP.NET using SignalR and SqlDependency](http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency)
- [SignalR with SQL server query notification](http://gkulshrestha.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/signalr-with-sql-server-query-notification/)

The article has suggested to enable Service broker on the database level.

```
SELECT name, is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases

ALTER DATABASE DemoDatabase SET ENABLE_BROKER
GO

GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO "DemoUserTesting"
```

Is there any impact on the performance at database level or any other issues if I enable Service broker on the database level?

Comment: This might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570337/disadvantages-of-sql-server-service-broker

regards,

Sachin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service broker is better for performance when using SQL as backplane for signalR, although it does also work with out it.

see here for full explanation http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-sql-server